# Open Source Training

Tags: industry-training

Cloud Foundry [open sourced their curriculum](https://basics-workshop.cfapps.io/) to train students on how to use it. Are there any other open source courses out there or organizations who collects training that is open sourced?

To clarify: I am looking for training for hardware/software that has been open sourced. Not open source software that has training.

Comment: The answer is trivially yes. Are you looking for something specific, or just a list of every product that trains users how to use their products?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for courseware: slides, labs, etc. that are released under an open source or creative commons license.

Comment: Note: Not all creative commons licences are complaint with the Open Source or Free Software definitions. Specifically none of the NC variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is a scientific journal that may include publications of such material that are what you are looking for: [The Journal of Open Source Education](http://jose.theoj.org), "An educator friendly journal for publishing computational learning modules and educational software."

Second, but I am not sure this is completely relevant to your question, there are the open source computational lesson from [The Carpentries](https://carpentries.org):

- Software Carpentry has [lessons](http://software-carpentry.org/lessons/) on the unix shell, version control (git and mercurial), programming in Python or R, R for Reproducible Scientific Analysis and more
- Data Carpentry has [lessons](https://datacarpentry.org/lessons/) more tailored to a research domain, on data analysis, but includes programming as well
- not yet part of The Carpentries, but under development is [HPC carpentry lessons](https://hpc-carpentry.github.io): shell, Python, Chapel, Snakemake
- there is also Library Carpentry, but their [lessons](https://librarycarpentry.org/lessons/) are more tailored to librarians

All these lessons are CC-BY.

Disclaimer: I am on The Carpentries Executive Council

Comment: Thank you. This is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: advertising(?) my own material here! Not sure if it is okay to do this, if not please let me know and I will remove this post!

I have also opened all the materials of a course I teach on Algorithms & Data structures here: https://gitlab.ewi.tudelft.nl/ads-maths/course-material
It's an introduction to complexity analysis of algorithms, basic data structures (lists, hashsets/maps, trees, and graphs), and some algorithms that operate on graphs (like traversals and shortest path algorithms).

Comment: Perfectly allowable as long as your affiliation is disclosed. Welcome back :)

Comment: Note: this material is NOT Open Sourced it is Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International. This licence dose not comply with the Open Source definition, Or the Free Software definition. Most Creative commons licences are compliant, but none of the NC (NonCommercial) ones are.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for pointing that out, I should talk to my university about this then, as this is what they recommend I put on it ;(

So am I right in understanding that this is okay for slides etc, but not for the implementation assignments? Or not even that?